# Ошибка сегментирования

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Matrix {
int m, n;
double **matrix;
double *data ;
} Matrix;

Matrix * createMatrix ( int m, int n ) {
Matrix *matrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix)*m*n);
if (!matrix) {
              printf("malloc error\n");
              return NULL;
              }
matrix->data = malloc(sizeof(double)*n);
if (!matrix->data) {
              printf("malloc error\n");
              return NULL;
              }
  int i, j;
 for (i=0; i<m; i++){
 for (j=0; j<n; j++){
 matrix->matrix[i][j]='0';

 }
 }
 for (i=0; i<m; i++){
 for (j=0; j<n; j++){
   printf ("Stop5 \n");
 }
 printf("\n");
 }
 return matrix;       
 }

void destroyMatrix ( Matrix* matrix ){
free(matrix->data);
free(matrix);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
if (argc!=3) {
printf("\nОшибка количества аргументов: \n");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int p;
int k;
p=atoi(argv[1]);
k=atoi(argv[2]);
 createMatrix (  p,  k );
 return 0;
 }
```

Матрица m на n Ошибка сегментирования в строке 25 (matrix->matrix[i][j]='0';). Подскажите где ошибка?

Answer (score 5):

Ну, вроде бы очевидно: вы неправильно выделяете память.

Под `Matrix` вам надо ровно `sizeof(Matrix)` места, а вы почему-то выделяете `sizeof(Matrix)*m*n`. Под `matrix->data` вам нужно, судя по всему, `sizeof(double)*m*n`, а вы выделяете всего `sizeof(double)*n`.

Но хуже всего с `matrix->matrix`: вы вообще не инициализируете этот указатель, и почему-то пытаетесь пользоваться им. Если вы объясните, какую семантику вы хотите для `matrix->matrix`, можно будет сказать, как его *нужно* инициализировать. Обычной практикой является вообще не использовать внутренние двойные указатели, и хранить данные в по адресу `data[m * i + j]`.

---

Окей, мы хотим, чтобы `matrix->matrix[i][j]` давало элемент матрицы с индексами `i`, `j`. Для этого есть несколько конкурирующих путей. Смотрите, как можно выделять память для данных вашей матрицы.

1) Выделяем память целым куском. Это тот путь, по которому вы идёте сейчас. У вас всего `m * n` элементов, значит вы выделяете сплошной кусок памяти размером `m * n * <размер одного элемента>`, то есть, `m * n * sizeof double`. Окей, как мы будем располагать данные в этом куске? Очевидное решение — сначала 0-ую строку (`m` элементов), впритык за ней 1-ую (ещё `m` штук), затем 2-ую и т. д. Теперь, чем должно быть `matrix->matrix[i][j]`? При пробегании индекса `j` от 0 до `n` выражение должно пробежать `i`-ую строку, значит, `matrix->matrix[i]` должно указывать на *начало* `i`-ой строки. Как это обеспечить? Можно сделать так: выделить массив указателей `matrix->matrix`, и *инициализировать* эти указатели нужными адресами! *Упражнение на понимание*: чему равен указатель в `matrix->matrix[i]`?

2) Выделяем память построчно. Если мы пойдём этим путём, нам вовсе не нужен указатель `data`. Для такого пути, мы выделяем сначала массив указателей на строки `matrix->matrix`, и затем не вычисляем значение указателей, а выделяем память для каждой строки отдельно (при помощи `malloc`), и запоминаем указатели на выделенную память в соответствующем элементе массива. Этот пример несколько легче к пониманию и интуитивнее, хотя и требует большего количества аллокаций.

3) Гибридный путь: выделение двумерного массива. Такое работает только если вам известен размер матрицы *во время компиляции*. Вы объявляете внутренний `matrix` как `double[m][n]`, и всё вычисление индексов перенимает на себя компилятор. Это самый простой и очевидный путь, но поскольку в вашем коде необходимо задание `m` и `n` во время выполнения, этот путь исключён.

Дерзайте! Вам придётся разобраться в указателях, это основа основ, без них никуда.

Comment: Это лабораторная работа, я не силен в си, только начинаю изучать. Я то понял что то не так с выделением памяти, но как исправить не знал. А указатели для меня вообще "темный лес". В лабе условие " В итоге обращение matrix->matrix[i][j] должно вести к обращению к i-ой строке и j-ому столбцу"
Если можно откоректируйте как надо программу. Спасибо

Comment: @Wolf: если вы не разбираетесь в указателях — самое время разобраться в них. Сейчас дополню ответ, но полного кода, извините, не дам. Думайте сами, иначе вы никогда не научитесь.